# xrdp can't mount drives after update

Tags: usb, mount

I recently updated xrdp after setting up Ubuntu pro. Now I can't mount any drives when I'm remoted into my Ubuntu machine using xorgxrdp

ii xorgxrdp 1:0.2.17-1build1 amd64 Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) modules for X.org
ii xrdp 0.9.17-2ubuntu2 amd64 Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) server

When I try to mount a drive in the files application or disks application it says "Unable to access "drive_name" An operation is already pending. How do I fix this? Thanks.

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3